# Git - Agile workflow supporting modifications to existing interfaces

Tags: git, version-control, workflow, branch

I have a question regarding on how to efficiently use Git (or any VCS I guess) when in the process of making modifications to existing code, particularly already utilised interfaces.

In our project, consisting of a team of seven, we are having two permanent branches, **master** and **dev**. In addition, we have feature-branches for features, fixes, etc, much like [this methodology](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). However, we have a bit of an issue, an issue that I have had before: How does one, as painless as possible, make changes to interfaces that is being used by code that is worked on in other branches? To illustrate, we have this:

```
dev -> 
    feat1
       - Modified Interface.code due to architectural changes.
       - Modified Class.code due to the interface changing.
    feat2
       - Modified Class.code due to changes in requirements or new features/fixes being introduced.
```

As you can see, the branch **feat1** modified an interface and therefore had to modify other code with dependencies to the changes. This is obviously to keep the code free from errors when merging the branch back into **dev** upon feature completion, keeping a working integrated version of the software.

The issue is that the code depending on the changed interface also is modified in another branch in order to implement necessary features/stories. Merging this feature back into **dev** later will most likely be a painful process, which is why I wonder how to actually proceed in these situations.

*In the actual project, we have an architectural change to one of our brokers, and that change will have repercussions in all existing feature branches utilising the broker since they branched of dev before we decided to make the change. While we could wait with integrating the broker changes until the other features are merged back into dev, that would block parts of the development and hinder us from delivering on all stories for the end of the iteration.*